# Prevent Rails from adding controller name as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This should be a simple thing but I am not able to prevent rails 6.0 from adding the name of the controller as a parameter. How can I do that? I really don't like the warning:

```
Unpermitted parameter :user
```

when I call `permit` on `params` in the controller.

My routes looks like this:

```
  post '/signin', to: 'users#sign_in'
```

and I have implemented `UsersController#sign_in` method.
When I inspect `params` in the controller I will always find a `user` key even if I am not passing it from the client.

Comment: I think the bit about `wrapped_parameters` is what you are looking for. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters.  I think you would need to turn those off in your config file? https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.3/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

Comment: You are right @RockwellRice I would have never thought it was something like that! I had to disable `wrap_parameters` by setting `wrap_parameters format: []` in an initializer. I don't remember enabling it so it must be enabled by default. Thanks so much! You can also add an answer to this question so that I can accept it if you like